# Toggle multiple checkboxes on mouse left button down and drag in wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I want to toggle the check state of all the checkboxes in wpf DataGrid when user drags over it while the mouse left button is down. It means when user press the mouse left button down and drags over DataGrid, all the cells of type 'DataGridCheckBoxColumn' which fall under this drag area should change the check state.

I'm able to achieve this by getting the collection of selected cells and toggeling the checkbox state, But it works fine only if there are few rows in grid and vertical scrollbar is not present. When i add more rows to the grid so that there is a vertical scroll bar present on grid this technique does not work. It toggles the checkboxes in drag area and lot of other check boxes down the view area of grid (it's kind of paging area, as if DataGrid is dividing the window into multiple pages and selecting those checkboxes into every page).

**What i have tried**

1. toggle checkboxes by getting the SelectedCells collection
2. Toggle by getting the checkboxes under the blue box of selection from the VisualTreeHelper
3. Toggle by looping the rows and columns which are under drag area by getting the row indexes and column indexes

All the approaches result into same behavior.
I want to understand where the mistake in this approach is. The xaml and code behind code I used for first approach is

.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MultipleCheckboxSelection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultipleCheckboxSelection"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,29" Name="userGrid" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="userGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-1"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-2"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-3"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-4"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-5"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-6"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<Person> People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            People.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "First", LastName = "Last", Age = 20 });
        }
        userGrid.ItemsSource = People;
    }

    private void userGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<DataGridCellInfo> selectedCells = userGrid.SelectedCells;

        foreach (var dataGridCell in selectedCells)
        {
            if (dataGridCell.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn)
            {
                var checkBox = dataGridCell.Column.GetCellContent(dataGridCell.Item) as CheckBox;
                if (null != checkBox)
                {
                    checkBox.IsChecked = !checkBox.IsChecked;
                }
            }
        }
        userGrid.UnselectAllCells();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

[image of result for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po1xu.png)

I'm using .net 4.6.1. A little help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My application has different type of checkbox columns. Each type can have 0 or more checkbox columns which are always placed together. These columns are added at run time by user and also can be removed at run time. Let's say i have 3 types of checkbox columns (T1, T2, T3). All the columns which are added for T1 will be placed together next to each other and same for other 2 types. If i maintain a list of bool values in my data context i'll have to do lot of work to maintain the correct values in list as columns are added and deleted at particular positions. For e.g. say user deletes a previously added column at position 6, then i'll have to loop through all the rows of grid and re-arrange the list by deleting the bool value for deleted column. Same will be required if a new column is inserted somewhere in between. It might not be good for performance also.

Comment: It is generally better to store data in the ViewModel rather than in the view. I would still suggest looping through the items and adding/removing columns properties. If you have a set limit to the amount of columns that can be added you could hide the extra columns, and then make them visible as needed. I have an app that has over 30 columns in a DataGrid that can be shown or hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in a DataGrid the actual checkbox controls are 'reused'. Instead of changing the checkbox control you should be changing the underlying data (added to your person class).

Then bind like this:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-1" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedColumn1}"/>
```

Then you would actually change the underlying data like this:

```
private void userGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = userGrid.SelectedItems;

    foreach (var item as Person in selectedItems)
    {
        item.IsCheckedColumn1 = true;
    }
    userGrid.UnselectAllCells();
}
```

You also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your person class.

**EDIT to answer comment**:

If you have a variable amount of checkboxes you could use a `List<bool>`.

Change the value like this:

```
item.IsChecked[0] = true;
```

You can bind to the list like this:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column-1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked[0]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem Neil. I'm sorry but i missed out one of the important detail. In my problem description i have configured 6 columns with check boxes, but in real scenario number of columns with check boxes are created at run time (It can be any number > 1). so i can not include them in by data bindings. Is there any other way to generate new checkbox for every cell. Will it help if i create a template column and add checkbox control inside that?

Comment: i have edited my original question due to the limited character limits for comments.